# How to connect the Db and get the data from table in Joomla php

Tags: joomla

I want to connect the Joomla DB and i have created table in PHPmyAdmin.
And want to get the row and values from the field.

Comment: Be more specific. With what part are you having problems with?

Answer (score 0):

Best way when having a proper JTable:

```
$row =& JTable::getInstance('my_table', '');
$row->load($id);
```

When working without JTable:

```
$db = &JFactory::getDbo();  
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM #__table WHERE id ='.$id;
$db->setQuery($sql);
$object = $db->loadObject();
```

OFC you can make that more elegant inside MVC. BUT for starters maybe enough.

Answer (score 0):

```php
$db = JFactory::getDBO();

$query = "select id,title from #__content";

$db->setQuery($query);

$result = $db->loadObjectList();//here we got array of stdClass===prepared objects in PHP 5.3

foreach($result as $res){
  echo $res->id."".$res->title;
}
```